# Tensorflow showing perfect accuracy without training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running the following code, but I'm getting the output `step 0, training accuracy 1`, which seems to imply that the network is perfect without any training, which is obviously wrong.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

input_size = 4
input_shape = (-1, 2, 2, 1)

x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_size])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W_fc = weight_variable([input_size, 1])
b_fc = bias_variable([1])

y_conv = tf.matmul(x1, W_fc) + b_fc

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(200):
        batch = [((0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0)),
                  ((0,), (1,), (2,))]
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                    x1: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x1: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
```

The code is mostly from the tensorflow mnist example, but rearranged a bit. Obviously not my full code, but the root cause should be the same as I get exactly the same problem with the much larger network and more complex data.

Because the network is tiny (barely even a network) I'd be expecting really low value, but I'm just getting a consistant 100% accuracy from the get-go. Commenting out the training step also does nothing. Is there something obvious I've forgotten? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following line

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
```

you are using `tf.argmax` whose output is `0` always because you have only one output. `Argmax` is used to get the category label with the maximum value and since there is only one category here, the output is always 0.

You'll also have to replace your loss, since `softmax` is used with multiple categories. Or the best option you have is to `one hot` encode your labels and increase the number of outputs accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that's how it was working. I've now tried replacing the correct_prediction and accuracy lines with this code `expected = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]); accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(expected - y_conv))` Now it gets more and more accurate until around 9000 epochs when it starts getting worse and never gets better. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I ended up fixing it by replacing the softmax with mean_squared_error. I tried replacing it with `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`, `tf.losses.cosine_distance` and several others that all didn't work, but mean squared error did. Do you know why this one works but not the others?